# Выподающее меню

Tags: javascript, html

Есть список `ul li`

```
<ul class="donate_ul">
    <li>текст
        <p>текст</p>
    </li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.donate_ul li').click(function(){
            $('.donate_ul p').toggle(this);
        })
    })
</script>
```

Как сделать чтобы при клике на `li` появлялась `p`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тебе нужно менять контекст, где искать `p`. Это делается так: `$('p', this).toggle();`, где `p` - элемент, `this` - текущий `li` по которому был произведен клик.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.donate_ul li').click(function(){
    $('p', this).toggle();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="donate_ul">
  <li>текст
    <p>текст1</p>
  </li>
  <li>текст
  </li>
  <li>текст
    <p>текст3</p>
  </li>
  <li>текст</li>
</ul>
```